# Flutter socket_io_client Room Rejoin Issue After Login/Logout

Tags: flutter, sockets, socket.io, flutter-bloc

I have implemented a Flutter application using the socket_io_client library to establish a real-time communication with a server. However, I'm facing an issue where the application fails to join a room and emit messages after logging out and logging back in, unless I perform a hot restart.

Steps taken:

- Used the AppBloc class to handle user authentication and socket initialization.
- Added the _initializeSocket method to establish a socket connection and emit a joinUserRoom event with the user ID.
- Implemented the AppLogoutRequested event to disconnect the socket upon logout and the AppUserChanged event to reinitialize the socket with the user information upon logging back in.

Expected behavior:

- Upon logging out, the socket should disconnect and stop emitting events.
- Upon logging back in, the socket should reconnect and emit a joinUserRoom event with the user ID to join the user room.
- The socket should successfully join the room and be able to emit messages for real-time communication.

However, the actual behavior is that after logging out and logging back in, the socket fails to join the user room and emit messages unless a hot restart is performed."

```dart
class AppBloc extends Bloc<AppEvent, AppState> with ChangeNotifier {
  AppBloc({required AuthService authenticationRepository, bool authenticated = false})
      : _authenticationRepository = authenticationRepository,
        super(
          authenticated
              ? AppState.authenticated(authenticationRepository.currentUser)
              : const AppState.unauthenticated(),
        ) {
    on<AppUserChanged>(_onUserChanged);
    on<AppLogoutRequested>(_onLogoutRequested);
    _userSubscription = _authenticationRepository.user.listen(
      (user) {
        add(AppUserChanged(user));
        notifyListeners();
      },
    );

    if (authenticated && _authenticationRepository.currentUser.isNotEmpty) {
      _initializeSocket(authenticationRepository.currentUser);
    }
  }

  void _initializeSocket(User currentUser) {
    socket = IO.io('http://localhost:3000', <String, dynamic>{
      'transports': ['websocket'],
    });

    socket.emit('joinUserRoom', currentUser.id);
  }

  late IO.Socket socket;

  final AuthService _authenticationRepository;
  late StreamSubscription<User> _userSubscription;

  void _onUserChanged(AppUserChanged event, Emitter<AppState> emit) {
    if (event.user.isNotEmpty) {
      _initializeSocket(event.user);
    } else {
      _disconnectSocket();
    }

    emit(
      event.user.isNotEmpty ? AppState.authenticated(event.user) : const AppState.unauthenticated(),
    );

    notifyListeners();
  }

  void _disconnectSocket() {
    if (socket.connected) socket.disconnect();
  }

  void _onLogoutRequested(AppLogoutRequested event, Emitter<AppState> emit) {
    _disconnectSocket();
    _authenticationRepository.logOut();
    emit(const AppState.unauthenticated());
    notifyListeners();
  }

  @override
  Future<void> close() {
    _disconnectSocket();
    _userSubscription.cancel();
    socket.dispose();
    return super.close();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to enable force new to reconnect. You can enable it while initializing socket. You have to change this code block:

```dart
 void _initializeSocket(User currentUser) {
    socket = IO.io('http://localhost:3000', <String, dynamic>{
      'transports': ['websocket'],
    });

    socket.emit('joinUserRoom', currentUser.id);
  }
```

to:

```dart
 void _initializeSocket(User currentUser) {
    socket = IO.io('http://localhost:3000', IO.OptionBuilder().setTransports(['websocket']).enableForceNew().build());

    socket.emit('joinUserRoom', currentUser.id);
  }
```